# Interact with .exe file using python

Tags: python-3.x

1. I have successfully opened the required .exe file.
2. I want to perform various click event inside that exe file after it has open
3. I want to upload a file in there after that.

I have opened the exe file using the below code:

```py
import subprocess, time

process = subprocess.Popen(['temp.exe', 'Continue\n', '1\n'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(10)
output, error = process.communicate(input=['Continue >\n','1\n'])

print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

Actual Output : I was successful only at opening the .exe file

Expected Output : I am expecting to perform various click actions in the .exe file following which I want to upload a file in the same .exe file.

Comment: I believe you can achieve that using [PyAutoIt](https://github.com/jacexh/pyautoit).

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I am unable to access the button with that either. Any other suggestions might be useful

Comment: No, sorry, that's all I know.